# UITextView resize its superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, autolayout

I have this UITextView as subview from a superview. I need to change the height of UITextView dynamically based on its text content, I can do it easily with this code through UITextView delegate method

```
CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
textView.frame = newFrame;
```

But the problem is, the superview doesn't resized correctly based on its subviews height changed (UITextView), is there any advice how to do such task?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];

CGRect frame = textView.superView.frame;
frame.size.height -= textView.frame.size.height;
frame.size.height += newSize.height;
textView.superView.frame = frame;    

CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
textView.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: I use your code inside `- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView`, and it doesn't gives the expected result. The superview keep goes down (because the height is changed), the textView's frame is not changed at all. Are you sure that this kind of task is not considering if the user tap the 'enter' key to make a new line inside the textView ?

Comment: COuld you please share the 2 iOS Simulator screens here. 
1. Before textView height changing.
2. After altering the TextView height. @invalidlogin

Comment: this is textView before changing anything: http://goo.gl/GFOOyd and this is the one after altering the textView height: http://goo.gl/QTDiaG

Comment: Ok, I rectified the issue, and posted new answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25480116/2504534 here.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in `- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView`,

It will work fine.

```
CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
if (!CGRectEqualToRect(textView.frame, newFrame))
{
    CGRect frame = textView.superview.frame;
    frame.size.height -= textView.frame.size.height;
    frame.size.height += newSize.height;
    textView.superview.frame = frame;
    textView.frame = newFrame;
}
```

Comment: This code gives the same result, superview height keep goes down while the textView frame is not change at all.

Comment: Check for `autolayout` property in your screen .xib file. You should disable the `autolayout` as this property makes some constraints automatically which may lead to some UI issues might be as yours problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm using auto layout, somehow, I can't turning off the auto layout feature, since I still use it for another control in my app. The codes are work perfectly without autolayout, so this solution is not working in my problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I made it work.

1. Setup autolayout that UITextView pin its superview edges especially top  and bottoms. UITextview editable = YES ;
2. Make a Pointer to NSLayoutConstraint to UITextView's height

Now you can change UITextView's height by its delegate like this.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    if (newSize.height > TextViewMinHeight) {
        textviewHeight.constant= newSize.height;
    }
}
```

Enjoy.

Also you cannot fix UITextView's height but you can make a constraint that let UITextView's height greater or equal to a number .

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue on xcode 8. My issue was if I changed superview height at the same time I was changing the textview height.. The text view would not change. It would only change if I only changed the textview height.

My solution was setting an outlet to the height constraint for the textview and changing the height there.

I still don't understand why the constraints wound't allow the textview to change with it's superview.